# Can’t access Firestore from lambda(http.get is fine)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, lambda

I’m trying to push data from lambda to Firestore, but every time trigger time out.

I did some research,
I tested locally.

Lambda with vpc(now it can access internet and call cloud function).

Added

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

After i increase the lambda execution time out from 3s to 10s,it woorked.